# What does `type` keyword actually means when used in a type definition?

Tags: delphi, types, keyword

I've recently read some lines of the *VCL* source code and found the definition of the `TCaption` type:

```
TCaption = type string;
```

I've always thought it was just another name for `string` type and I was thinking that it was defined as follows:

```
TCaption = string;
```

So, I've looked for [documentation](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=type&ExpandCode1=Yes) about the `type` keyword and I've found this:

> 1. type Name = Existing type
>      Refers to an existing type, such as **string** by a new **Name**.
> 2. type Name = type Existing type
>      This has the same effect as above, but ensures that at run time, variables of this type are identified by
>      their new type name, rather than the existing type name.

After reading it, I'm still confused and I don't understand what *"...ensures that at run time, variables of this type are identified by their new type name..."* actually means.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg: Where should the _VCL_ tag be used if not here?

Comment: DelphiBasics is like W3Schools for web developers (it's not updated). @ExDev, your question is about RTL, VCL is visual controls related.

Comment: Your question is not related to `Vcl` or any other component library. It is more a question about the language itself.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: You're right, it was actually a wrong tag

Comment: @Victoria: You're right, I'll look for embarcadero's documentation first.

Comment: @Tom, do you think we can speak about RTL in case of compiler intrinsics stuff? I was probably wrong with my comment. I'm just splitting Delphi (more or less) into two parts, visual and runtime part, hence I thought this might be related to runtime part. What do you think?

Comment: @Victoria IMO, it is a question about a certain syntax and how that is interpreted by the compiler. I understand your pow, especially since RTTI gets involved, but still I maintain it is a language question.

Comment: @Tom, definitely is. I fully understand your correct removing of VCL tag. I was just wondering if I could clarify question like this as RTL one.

Comment: Dear @Victoria You don't have to ask for my permission ;) Just ... do it!

Comment: @Victoria RTL = Run Time _Library_. This language feature affects the _compiler_. You could take Tom's answer: remove the unnecessary form dependency, and move it into a single DPR file repro with zero _library_ dependencies. This should make it clear that while it also has an impact on RTL, there is no grey are here. _It's clearly a language question and **not** a library question of any sorts_. (Unfortunately OP's reference to flawed 3rd-party documentation seems to have created unnecessary confusion here.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type declaration like

```
TCaption = type string;
```

creates new type with different RTTI information. Also it cannot be used as `var` parameter of function if `string` type needed.

New RTTI information "...ensures that at run time, variables of this type are identified by their new type name...". So if you try to get type name for an instance of `TCaptionSame = string;`, you'll get `string`, while for `TCaption` type variable you'll get `TCaption`

To get more exact information, it would better to refer to [official help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Data_Types,_Variables,_and_Constants_Index_(Delphi))

Answer (score 12):

Consider the following code, and note that the procedure `Check()` has a `var` parameter:

```
type
  Ta = string;       // type alias
  Tb = type string;  // compatible but distinct new type

procedure Check(var s: string);
begin
  ShowMessage(s);
end;

procedure TMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: Ta;
  b: Tb;
begin
  a := 'string of type Ta,';
  b := 'string of type Tb.';
  Check(a);
  Check(b);
end;
```

`Check(b)` results in a compiler error:
E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

In the above, type `Tb` is compatible with `string` in that you can f. ex. assign `a := b`, but it is distinct in that the `type identifier` (under the hood) has a different value, and therefore not accepted as argument for `Check(var s: string)`.

Comment: [Specializing a type](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITLE_609) will help make code stronger and safer. One of the biggest failure in NASA history was Mars Climate Orbiter. A variable type error burn up a $327.6 million project in minutes, when one engineering group working on the thrusters measured in English units of pounds-force seconds, whereas the others used metric Newton-seconds. The result of that inattention is now lost in space, possibly in pieces.

Comment: Note that [Delphi string helpers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper) are so broken that if you define you own `type string` then you can't access to the `string` helper pseudo-methods. They have broken a rich feature of pascal programming since decades to add a C#/Java-like feature.